# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 1: invalid start byte -- Pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=CompanyDSN')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding ='ISO-8859-1')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Music")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

I am trying to connect to DSN and get data but it keep throwing me error.
I already tried to set encoding feature.
The database is Basis ( rarely used database ) installed on linux server..

The error I am getting is

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Any suggestions ?
I read many forums but couldn't figure. Also couldn't use it with pandas dataframe?
Please help me in this

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Also, please show the full traceback.

Comment: @TurePålsson Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\GLMH.py", line 9, in <module>
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [BASIS][BBj ODBC Driver]Function not implemented. (1) (SQLGetData)')